# data base in android

Tags: android, database

I am going to write an application that requires data base. 
I am going to need four tables and each table is going to maintain information of one screen of the app. 
my question is that can I create one database helper class and put all the tables in it or should I create 4 different helper classes and put each table in one separate class . 
does it make any difference? 
thanks

Comment: One database helper class.

Answer (score 1):

> can I create one database helper class

Yes. One is enough. Also think about to make your `DatabaseHelper` as [`Singleton`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

> put all the tables in it or should I create 4 different helper classes
>   and put each table in one separate class

Like i wrote above, you will put all tables into one class.

> does it make any difference?

Result will be same but difference is i guess that you write less code, you will always have one instance of Helper, code will be more clean and better readable.

Imagine some business company that has big database with 20 tables. Still company has only one database.

You can imagine [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) as one big database(it wraps all required logic). Hence it's not logic to create 4 different classes where each wraps one table. It's like you would have 4 databases with one table.

### My suggestion:

Is to create one universal `DatabaseHelper` which will wrap all required logic and then to achieve clean and working solution you can create four classes which will implement `CRUD` operations for each table.

### Example:

```
public class UserTools {

   private SQLiteOpenHelper handler;
   private SQLiteDatabase db;

   public UserTools(SQLiteOpenHelper handler) {
      this.handler = handler;
   }

   public void insert(<data>) { ... }

   public void update(<data>) { ... }

   public void delete(<data>) { ... }

   public List<DataType> getAll() { ... }

   public DataType getObject(<data>) { ... }

   private final synchronized SQLiteDatabase openWrite(SQLiteOpenHelper handler) {
      return handler.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   private final synchronized SQLiteDatabase openRead(SQLiteOpenHelper handler) {
      return handler.getReadableDatabase();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one database helper class, and initialize it somewhere in your application and pass it around in your activities.

You can create a class for each table like this:

```
public class CartTable {
// database table
public static final String TABLE_CART = "cart";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_CART_GROCERY_ID = "cart_grocery_id"; // this is grocery_id
public static final String COLUMN_CART_GROCERY_NAME = "cart_grocery_name";

// database creation SQL statement
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_CART
        + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_CART_GROCERY_ID + " integer unique, "
        + COLUMN_CART_GROCERY_NAME + " text);";

public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(CategoryTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
            + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CART);
    onCreate(database);
}
```

}

and create a database helper class that does something like this in onCreate:

```
class myDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        CartTable.onCreate(db);
    } 
    //.....get read/write database methods etc
}
```

finally, create a singleton class that creates and maintains an instance of it

```
class myDatabase{
    private static MyDatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;

    public static MyDatabaseHelper getInstance(){
        if (myDatabaseHelper == null)
            myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper();
        return myDatabaseHelper;
    }
}
```

Then from any actvitiy you can get it through myDatabase.getInstance()